# MYSQL choosing value used of column with different values when Grouping

Tags: mysql

Sample mysql table:

```
carnum,cartype,carname
1,sportscar,mustang
2,sportscar,mustang GT
3,sportscar,mustang GT
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT carname, cartype
FROM cars
GROUP BY cartype
```

I get:

```
mustang,sportscar
```

What I want is:

```
mustang GT,sportscar
```

Is there a way to make the group use the most recent carname (mustang GT) rather than the first one (mustang)? I tried sorting in various ways but had no luck.

Thanks very much.

Comment: This is sort of a fruitless effort.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of records.  This is not really how `GROUP BY` is intended to be used.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll go about it a different way.

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY carnum DESC LIMIT 1;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

try with this one

```
select carname, cartype from cars 
where carnum in(
select max(carnum) from cars group by cartype
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try:

```
Select Distinct carname, cartype FROM cars
```

or

```
Select top 1 carname, cartype FROM cars Order by carname
```

This will give you what you want in this case, but depending on your final goal, may not be ideal. If you provide more details, we may be able to help more.

Comment: If there is a problem with an answer, comments (not just a downvote) would be appreciated.